# Filter an indexed array with one regex filter using filter_var_value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a csv file that has lines of data, each row can have variable number of values.
I want to filter each line of the file to see if it has special characters or wrong values, if yes, the line will be skipped from the whole process.
So here is my code:

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen('file.csv', "r")) !== false) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== false) {
        $keys = array('key');
        foreach($line as $value){
            $arr[] = array_fill_keys($keys,$value);
        }
       $args = array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                    'options' => array('regexp' => '/[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\s-\/]*/'), );
       $result = filter_var_array($arr,$args);
       var_dump($result);

    }
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

My problem here, is that the line as an array of values, is an indexed array, without keys, and I tried to fill in the keys but I still don't get good results and the values don't get filtered.
My second problem, is that I want to apply one filter on all the values, this filter is a regexp, so I cant just do this :

```
filter_var_array($arr,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP);
```

Because I'll have to provide the `options`:

> `PHP Warning:  filter_var_array(): 'regexp' option missing`

Something like this doesn't work eather :

```
filter_var_array($line,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,[ 'options' => array('regexp' => '/[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\s-\/]*/')]);
```

because the parameters of filter_var_array should be 2 arrays and a boolean:

> `PHP Warning:  filter_var_array() expects parameter 3 to be boolean`

So to sum up:

1. How to filter this file using one filter in the `filter_var_array`?
2. If it's impossible, is there a better way to analyse the whole file
   and see if the content matches the regexp ?

Comment: Create keys and pass them for filter array, maybe?

Comment: That's what I tried above, In the foreach loop. @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a line (array) has 4 elements in it (one,two,three,four), then your loop:

```
$keys = array('key');
foreach($line as $value){
    $arr[] = array_fill_keys($keys,$value);
}
```

will create:

```
$arr=array(
    0=>array("key"=>"one"),
    1=>array("key"=>"two"),
    2=>array("key"=>"three"),
    3=>array("key"=>"four"),
)
```

That seems unnecessarily multidimensional.
Also, your regex is doomed to be true, it is asking for 0 or more of the acceptable characters anywhere in the string.
I'll make a regex pattern assumption and adjust it for you.
Try this:

```
foreach($line as $key=>$value){
    $arr["k$key"]=$value;
    $filters["k$key"]=array(
                          'filter'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                          'options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\s-\/]*$/')
                          // the regex will allow an empty string
                          // or a string of any length containing only those characters.
                      );
}
$result=filter_var_array($arr,$filters);
if(in_array(false,$result)){
    echo "Line not valid";
}else{
    var_export($result);  // with no invalid values, $result == $arr
}
```

Here is a [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85121af1f26649b30cad1a6692725098bee4f89e).

Variable outputs:

```
$arr=array(
    'k0' => 'one',
    'k1' => 'two',
    'k2' => 'three',
    'k3' => 'four',
   )

$filter=array(
    'k0' => array(
        'filter' => 272,
        'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/'),
    ),
    'k1' => array(
        'filter' => 272,
        'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/'),
    ),
    'k2' => array(
        'filter' => 272,
        'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/'),
    ),
    'k3' => array(
        'filter' => 272,
        'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/'),
    )
)
```